# Progress bar based on how many times a button is clicked java

Tags: java, netbeans

I would like to know how to update a progress bar based on how many times a button is clicked. I am using Netbeans so I already have the progress bar and button implemented and everything.

What I want to do is have a button that is bound to the progress bar so each time you 
click the button, the progress bar goes up by 10%.

What I need help with is binding the button to the progress bar so it can actually do this and making the button so when you click it, update the bar.

Because I am using Netbeans you simply select the progress bar and it creates it's own jFrame and implements the progress bar all you have to do is add your handling code and that's where I need help.

Comment: Code would be nice. And please narrow down the question to a specific issue.

Comment: My issue is I'm new to the whole 'GUI' side of Java and am trying to make a progress bar go to 100% if a button is clicked 10 times for a project I don't really know how I would make this happen.

Comment: "I already have the progress bar and button implemented and everything"? Can you show this? What are you having trouble with specifically? If you break your whole problem into smaller parts, which part is giving you trouble? Do you know how to count the number of times the button was clicked? Do you know how to change the progress percentage? Are you having trouble binding this count to the progress?

Comment: Sorry I am horrible at this. I will edit my whole question.

Answer (score 0):

As if I correctly understand what you are saying, the pseudo code would be something like

```
button.addActionListener(new ActionListener()
{
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
    {
       myProgressBar.setProgress(myProgressBar.getProgress()+0.1);  
    }
});
```

Comment: Thank you, I will give this a try and let you know.

Comment: This doesn't seem to work. As Netbeans gives you the option to add and action listener to the button so it auto generates it like this 'private void jButton1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {'  then when I add everything but defining the new action listener it doesn't seem to work.

Comment: As I said this is a pseudo code. Look for the JavaDOC and see whats the "onClick" method of a JButton and so on...